React Native expo-camera installation
While trying to install expo-camera on Windows I am getting this error again and again.
Can somebody please tell me how to resolve this.
(https://i.sstatic.net/qkiqt.png)
I am trying to take a picture from my camera using react native and for that I need these packages to be installed. And I am getting these errors and i don't know how to resolve them.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Please add more info: Which version of expo-cli, Nodejs you use in your project

Your error screenshot clearly says that the "Expo cli" you are using, has been deprecated, which means it is discontinued.
It is suggesting you to use the "new Expo CLI" instead, which comes bundled in the Expo package.
Now, to install the Expo-camera, all you need to do is run : npx expo install expo-camera
The above command will install Expo-Camera module for your native React app.
The documentation is here : https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-camera
Please note that Expo-camera module requires "Expo" to be installed first.
To install Expo, run this : npx install-expo-modules@latest
Documentation: https://docs.expo.dev/bare/installing-expo-modules/
If this is helpful, mark as Answer
